# I get the following error with rnn function: Error in x %*% model$time_synapse[[i]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: arrays, r, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a recurrent neural network on R with package 'rnn'. I tried to implement one as follows:

```
Y <- matrix(df_train$Y, nrow=48)
X <- matrix(df_train$insolvency, nrow=48)
```

It worked perfectly. However when I try to implement a network with X as an array combining 2 variables:

```
X <- array(c(df_train$insolvency, df_train$comportement), dim=c(48, 44,2))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in x %*% model$time_synapse[[i]] :    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

However both my variables insolvency and comportement are numeric, with no NA... Do you know where it could come from? I've read that this error message pops when you have character variable. It isn't the case here...

Example of data:

```
insolvency  comportement  Y
  0.0019    0.000000e+00  2
  0.0015    0.000000e+00  2
  0.0015    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0016    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0016    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0016    2.981289e-02  0
  0.0016    2.279081e-03  0
  0.0016    5.357894e-03  0 
  0.0016    4.559373e-01  0
  0.0019    3.636734e-01  0
  0.0019    3.728338e-01  0
  0.0049    4.239274e-01  0
  0.0025    4.581197e-01  0
  0.0049    1.072687e-01  0
  0.0049    2.978970e-03  0
  0.0037    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0049    1.122552e-01  0
  0.0049    1.257744e-01  0
  0.0031    3.107757e-02  0
  0.0031    3.312815e-02  0
  0.0031    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0025    6.843268e-02  0
  0.0025    1.151147e-01  0
  0.0025    1.329283e-01  0
  0.0025    7.341950e-02  0
  0.0031    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0031    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0031    8.637882e-02  0
  0.0031    0.000000e+00  0
  0.0025    0.000000e+00  0
```

Here is the code I wrote that fails when trying to implement rnn:

```
nnet <- trainr(Y=Y, X=X, learningrate=0.05, hidden_dim = 16, numepochs = 250)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do there with the array. Just use cbind to combine both vectors into a matrix.

Comment: Thank you it works... I still don't understand why I had this error message

Comment: Well, I'm guessing here but I don't think the documentation says that a 3d array is acceptable input.

Comment: Actually documentation says that X must be a 3D array (dim 1: sample, dim 2: time, dim 3: variables)